# Arrays assembly

Tags: disassembly, windows, binary-analysis, c, static-analysis

I'm reversing my C array's programs where I'm storing numbers in arrays like this...

```
int marks[5];
marks[0] = 1;
marks[1] = 3;
marks[2] = 2;
marks[3] = 7;
marks[4] = 9;
```

so the compiler showing me the disassembly...

[image]

Actually, my question is why it is storing like this? by using `imul` first before storing 1 then before storing 7, and using `shl` for storing 3, 2, and 9.
Can anyone please help?
Fell free to edit it*

Comment: i think you have already been asked to post text not images

Comment: Actually, in visual studio 2017 I can't copy the assembly code as there's no option there so that's why I've use an image to present my point.

Comment: @RamessesII unless you have some strange VS, you can for sure copy assembly from there.

Comment: Lack of copy and paste (if true, which is unlikely) is not an excuse for posting an image of text. You can re-type it in a code block. It's not that much.

Answer (score 3):

those are pointer arithmetics
marks is an <<<;ADDRESS;>>>>>  assume 0x10000000
it points to an integer whose size is 4 in 32 bit machine
so the next integer will be at 0x10000004 ,
and the next will be at 0x10000008 and so on

&marks[0] = 0x10000000
&marks[1] = 0x10000004
&marks[2] = 0x10000008,c,10,14,18,.....nn

each of the 4 in the disassembly is sizeof(int) == 4
they are multiplied by 0 , 2^0 , 2^1,3 and 2^2 to result in 0,1,2,3,4 as indexes